# Scala: are all the methods of a Trait imported or just the one that are used?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, traits

I'm wondering if all the methods of a `Trait` are imported in a class which extends this `Trait` or just the used ones?

And with dependency injection?

Comment: Can you extend you second question, please. I don't get what you asking.

Comment: throw some code at me

Comment: Sounds like you got some of the terminology confused: "imported" means available for the _compiler_ - so of course everything is imported and not just "used ones", the whole point of importing stuff is to be _able_ to use it.

Comment: @talex If I inject a class inside an other, are all the methods imported or just the ones used in the class which is injecting the other class?

Comment: @tzachZohar: so at compile time, the compiler does not remove the unnecessary methods (unused methods)?

Comment: The compiled code might later be used by some other code unknown to the compiler, so all (non-private) methods _must_ be available, right? I think generally speaking the compiler doesn't _remove_ methods from classes (which isn't really related to "import" rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the methods which are marked `private` every other method will be available with the extending entity. The extending entity can choose to override or leave unimplementated, in which case the children of this entity has to deal with it.

```
trait A {
 private def a: Int = 1 //not available
 protected def b: Int = 2 //available inside extending entity
 def d: Int = 3 //available everywhere 
}

class B extends A {}
val x = new B()

x.a //error

x.b //error

x.d //prints 3
```

Coming to dependency injection

Lets say A and B are two interfaces or traits which do not hold parent/child relationship.

If you inject one entity into other. All public methods of that entity can be accessed by other